# How to make inference from a model using Lambda?

Tags: python, tensorflow, aws-lambda, multiprocessing, amazon-efs

I trained an image segmentation model with Mask-RCNN and my goal now is to make inference using AWS Lambda, for this I am modifying the [Deploy multiple machine learning models for inference on AWS Lambda and Amazon EFS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/deploy-multiple-machine-learning-models-for-inference-on-aws-lambda-and-amazon-efs/), my project tree is:

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── __init__.py
├── app.py
├── requirements.txt
└── maskrcnn
    ├── config.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── m_rcnn.py
    ├── visualize.py
    ├── mask_rcnn_coco.h5
    ├── mask_rcnn_object_0005.h5
    └── model.py
```

So instead of trying to load my models into the EFS mount point, I decided to load my models into the `maskrcnn` directory, which I have add a COPY statement in Dockerfile, using `COPY maskrcnn/ ./maskrcnn`.

When I invoke my code locally, it works perfectly. However, after deploying the project it doesn't work anymore. When I try to do inference through the endoint of the GATEWAY API, I get the following response:

```
[ERROR] OSError: [Errno 38] Function not implemented
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/app.py", line 32, in lambda_handler
    r = test_model.detect([image])[0]
  File "/var/task/maskrcnn/model.py", line 2545, in detect
    self.keras_model.predict([molded_images, image_metas, anchors], verbose=0)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_v1.py", line 988, in predict
    return func.predict(
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_arrays_v1.py", line 703, in predict
    return predict_loop(
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_arrays_v1.py", line 386, in model_iteration
    aggregator.create(batch_outs)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils_v1.py", line 446, in create
    SliceAggregator(self.num_samples, self.batch_size)))
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils_v1.py", line 355, in __init__
    self._pool = get_copy_pool()
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils_v1.py", line 323, in get_copy_pool
    _COPY_POOL = multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool(_COPY_THREADS)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 925, in __init__
    Pool.__init__(self, processes, initializer, initargs)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 196, in __init__
    self._change_notifier = self._ctx.SimpleQueue()
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/context.py", line 113, in SimpleQueue
    return SimpleQueue(ctx=self.get_context())
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 336, in __init__
    self._rlock = ctx.Lock()
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/context.py", line 68, in Lock
    return Lock(ctx=self.get_context())
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 162, in __init__
    SemLock.__init__(self, SEMAPHORE, 1, 1, ctx=ctx)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 57, in __init__
    sl = self._semlock = _multiprocessing.SemLock(
```

Comment: It seems that the user is not allowed to access the shared memory, but when running with root privileges, it works well. From what I've researched, POSIX semaphores are created in shared memory. So you need to make sure that users have `rw` permissions to `/dev/shm` for the semaphores to be created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to run the project once by changing the python version from 3.8 to 3.7 in Dockerfile.